# почему не работает выборка WHERE в SQL запросе

Tags: php, sql, pdo

схожу с ума, не понимаю почему не работает выборка WHERE в SQL запросе, помогите найти ошибку, по моему запросу выводит все записи из таблицы

```
$cat = intval($_GET["cat"]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tour WHERE `category` = $cat ";
$query = $pdo->query($sql); //возвращает объект
$tours = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Заранее спасибо за любую подсказку

Comment: A каково значение `$cat`?

Comment: В чём именно заключается «не работает»?

Comment: значение $cat из базы данных, страница категорий, выводит все категории

Answer (score 0):

Замените строку

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tour WHERE `category` = $cat ";
```

на

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tour WHERE `category` = '".$cat."'";
```

Comment: плейсхолдеры надо использовать

Comment: не решило проблему